# Prometheus' Alertmanager Slack webhook getting "alertmanager.yaml err="unsupported scheme \"\" for URL"

Tags: webhooks, prometheus, slack, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

I am trying to send Alertmananger alerts to Slack and I am successful in doing that with my customized template.

But now I want to send alerts to different channels and thus selecting different webhook from the configuration file and I am not able to do so and getting

```
component=configuration msg="Loading configuration file failed" file=/etc/alertmanager/config/alertmanager.yaml err="unsupported scheme \"\" for URL"
```

I am picking the webhook from a template file and the issue is mostly with the loading of the variable "slack.myorg.webhook"

**Alertmanager.yaml**

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
  slack_api_url: '{{ template "slack.myorg.webhook" . }}'
route:
  group_by: ['alertname']
  ...
  ...
  ...
templates: ['/etc/alertmanager/config/*.tmpl']
```

**slack-myorg-template.tmpl**

I will add my logic to select webhook on some labels later as of now just loading via a template

```
# To identify from which cluster the alerts are comming
{{ define "slack.myorg.username" }}Minikube{{ end }}

# select webhook
{{ define "slack.myorg.webhook" }}https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/XX/XX{{ end }}
```

**The only issue if slack.myorg.webhook is not perfectly loading into slack_api_url by calling '{{ template "slack.myorg.webhook" . }}'.**

Other things I tried

1. Just mentioning {{ define "slack.myorg.webhook"
   }}https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXX/XX/XX{{ end }} doesn't cause
   any issue.
2. If I do username: '{{ template "slack.myorg.webhook" .
   }}' under slack configuration it's not throwing error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slack_api_url` (as well as `api_url` from slack_config) don't support templating.

https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/2207#event-3127085200